# UWP Configuration file

Tags: c#, uwp, config

What is the best way to use a config file in a UWP application?

Store some string values in a config file that can be edited without that the application need to be rebuild everytime.

Somthing like a web.config file.

Comment: what values you wanted to add? eg: styles, resource string values or property parameters

Comment: @Hariprasadkasavajjala  string values, url's (a url can change in the future)

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to side-load the app, you could add a text or XML file to it (with the Build Action property set to Content) that contains some pre-defined configuration values and then read from this file at runtime. e.g.:

```
var sampleFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");
var contents = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
```

Comment: Ok will try this